# Does the solution to $u_t=-uu_x+0.1u_{xx}$ decay in time?

Tags: numerical-methods, partial-differential-equations

Consider the following PDE:
$$
\begin{align}
&u_t+uu_x=0.1u_{xx},\qquad 0<x<1,t>0\\
&u(x+1,t)=u(x,t),\qquad t\geq 0 \\
&u(x,0) = \sin 2\pi x,\qquad 0\leq x\leq 1
\end{align}
$$

I used two different numerical schemes(Finite difference and Spectral method) and implemented it by MATLAB to plot $u$ at $t = 0.21$. The results are very different:
[image: Using Finite Difference]
[image: Using Spectral Method]

Here are my questions:

- Is there a name for this nonlinear PDE?
- Does the solution to the PDE decay in time?
- [EDITED:]Which one of the figures above is close to the true solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the viscous Burger's equation, in wiki you might get what you want.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burger%27s_equation

BTW, by decay you mean the $C^0$norm decay?